# Javascript update on textarea style only after edit in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, textarea

I'm having a textarea in IE10 of which I am trying to update the style via some jQuery sliders and buttons.

I wrote a [small demo in JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/japaveh/zkFWR/16) to demonstrate the problem

There are 2 problems here in IE 10

1. The font is not updated in the correct direction and line-height is ignored
2. The buttons, needed to change the alignment, only work when the user starts to edit the content of the textearea instead of directly.

Both problems do not occur in Firefix and Chrome

I use the following jQuery commands to update the style

```
$("#area").css('font-size', fontSize + "px");
$("#area").css('line-height', lineHeight + "px");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok well I don't know why IE is so resistant to change, but it is.  IE doesn't like to do anything unless it has to.  So to get around this you have to grab the text that is there by setting it to a var and then re-enter it all in so that IE sees a change and then updates.

So here is the code from your fiddle...

```
$("#sliderFontSize").slider({
    range: "min",
    min: 10,
    max: 100,
    step: 10,
    slide: function (event, ui) {
        var fontSize = ui.value;
        var lineHeight = (fontSize * 1.3);
        $("#area").css('font-size', fontSize + "px");
        $("#area").css('line-height', lineHeight + "px");
    }
});

$("#alignLeft").click(function() {
    $("#area").css('text-align','left');
});

$("#alignRight").click(function() {
    $("#area").css('text-align','right');
});
```

So all you need to do is add...

```
var currentText = $("#area").text();
$("#area").text(currentText);
```

To your click functions...

```
$("#alignLeft").click(function() {
    $("#area").css('text-align','left');
    var currentText = $("#area").text();
    $("#area").text(currentText);
});

$("#alignRight").click(function() {
    $("#area").css('text-align','right');
    var currentText = $("#area").text();
    $("#area").text(currentText);
});
```

That should do it.